# How to display basic message on Ajax error in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've looked at a number of previous Stack Overflow questions but can't figure out how to apply it to my specific case.

In particular I've looked at a lot of solutions which tell you to set the form to remote, and use .js.erb files and many partial files. But this seems overly complex for what I want to do.

My app is querying an external API. When the first ajax call is successful it triggers another request (through another form on the page).

But on error, how do I simply add a simple red error message in a p tag to the top of the page (without reloading) saying a problem has occurred?

My controller is not setup in the best way as there is no database and it is just making requests to the API:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

    def index
      if params[:partner_code] && params[:restaurant_location_id] && params[:session_id] && params[:dining_date_and_time] && params[:size] && params[:first_name] && params[:last_name] && params[:bookEmail]
        if params[:reservationId]     
        end
      end
    end

    def new
      @reservation = Reservation.new params[:partner_code], params[:restaurant_location_id], params[:session_id], params[:dining_date_and_time], params[:size], params[:first_name], params[:last_name], params[:bookEmail]
    end

    def temp_page
    @cancel = Cancel.new params[:reservationId]
    end

    # Is this needed?
    def guests     
    end

    private

    def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:partner_code, :restaurant_location_id, :session_id, :dining_date_and_time, :size, :first_name, :last_name, :bookEmail, :confirmation_number, :reservationId)
    end

end
```

My ajax code:

```
$(function() {

  $('#partner_code').closest('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      // BELOW NOT NEEDED:
      //dataType: 'text',
      // contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function() {
          submitCancellation();
        },
      error: function() {
          errorMessage();
      }
    });
  });

  function submitCancellation() {
      console.log("Triggered Submit Cancellation");
      $('#reservationId').val($('#reservationId').attr('value'));
      // submit second form            
      $('#reservationId').closest('form').submit();
  }

  function errorMessage() {
    $("#error_message).html
  }


});
```

My view with two forms which on submit triggers the two ajax calls:

```
<!-- FIRST FORM -->
<%= form_tag(new_reservation_path, method: :post) do %>   

  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag :partner_code %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">    
   <%= text_field_tag :restaurant_location_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">    
    <%= text_field_tag :session_id %>
  </div>   

   <div class="date-field">    
    <%#= label_tag :dining_date_and_time %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :dateSubmit%>
  </div>

   <div class="field">    
    <%#= label_tag :dining_date_and_time %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :timeSubmit %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">    
    <%#= label_tag :size, 'Guests' %><br>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :size %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%#= label_tag :first_name %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%#= label_tag :last_name %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :last_name %>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <%#= label_tag :email %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :bookEmail %>
  </div>    

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Continue', name: nil, id: "bookSubmit" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <!-- SECOND FORM -->
    <%= form_tag(temp_page_reservations_path, method: :post) do %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= text_field_tag :reservationId %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is almost perfect. Here's what I see:

```
function errorMessage() {
  $("#error_message").html("An error occurred");
  $("#error_message").css('color', 'red');
}
```

I don't see the div `#error_message` in your view, so make sure you have that somewhere.